# How to map an object from JSON file to another object?

Tags: json, typescript

Here is my [json](/questions/tagged/json) file

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "firstName": "Tom",
      "lastName": "Yoda",
      "type": "guest",
      "id": "0",
      "gender": m,
      "data": { "age": 26, "born": "UK" }
    },
  ]
}
```

This `data` array could have more entries.

I have to map the values into an interface which looks like:

```ts
InterfacePerson {
 id: string;
 title: string;
 firstName: string;
 lastName: string;
 age: string;
 location: string;
}
```

I am unable to change the interface. So I'm trying to do some pseudo coding.

```
const list;

list = convertToInterfacePerson = (value): Array<InterfacePerson> => {
 return {
  id: value.id,
  title: if(value.gender === "m")? "Mr" : "Mrs",
  firstName: value.firstName,
  lastName: value.lastName,
  age: value.data.age,
  //...
 }
}
```

Comment: The title of the question contains the operation you want... `.map()`.  You are encouraged to try using it.  But the "pseudo coding" shown has a variety of syntax problems.  If you're struggling with JavaScript syntax in general then you probably want to work on that first.  For example, there is no `if` when using the ternary conditional operator.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were trying to use a conversion mapping function called `convertToInterfacePerson` but you hadn't set it up yet (separately from trying to use it). The code below shows it declared and used within a `map` Array method call. I believe this resolves the error(s) you were getting.

```js
// Copied in the JSON for demonstration
const sourceJson = {
  "data": [
    {
      "firstName": "Tom",
      "lastName": "Yoda",
      "type": "guest",
      "id": "0",
      "gender": "m",
      "data": { "age": 26, "born": "UK" }
    },
  ]
};

// Declared the InterfacePerson interface
interface InterfacePerson {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  age: string;
  location: string;
}

// Declared the conversion mapping function (optional parameter typing included)
const convertToInterfacePerson = (value: { firstName: string, lastName: string, type: string, id: string, gender: string, data: { age: number, born: string } }): InterfacePerson => {
  return {
    id: value.id,
    // Removed the `if` statement due to ternary conditional
    title: ((value.gender === "m") ? "Mr" : "Mrs"),
    firstName: value.firstName,
    lastName: value.lastName,
    // Wrapped the value.data.age in a string conversion
    age: String(value.data.age),
    location: value.data.born
  };
}

// Declared and assigned the list based on the returned array from the mapping function (each element is applied in the `convertToInterfacePerson` function)
const list = sourceJson.data.map(convertToInterfacePerson);

// Show the result of the conversion
console.log(JSON.stringify(list, null, 2));
```

And for a live example, check out this [TypeScript Playground script](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGEHsAcEsFMAmpYDtQBcAW9QCkBlAeQDlQAzSAJ1EXgFtJUBnDKgQw1iYFgAoAMZNWoZpACuVAfDxj0AXlABvfqFAAiRJ3bqAXKADaqtcuMmN5WFVYl29eHo0AVSPXUAaMyfUAbdjbsHfXUATUgtDy81dQwAT2ggjQBzcXhWSL5zaNhER3UABgys5PhUOio8t09MrM1tRyUNdiTEgCYANncNACNqVDyAVQBpdVAAXy8x6rUAXX4xgG5%20fhBQABF4AT8qJEwcUABJVAx4KnJ2aQAFU7kUY9Pz6X40E7OL3CPXx-hr6yZTGo5fSsKhoJJLGpcDA%20eDAthgiFqSzWDC2exw0GocHGPwBdGieFYxGgZqwgmY7E1HyQAScbioDEI%20bLPirDZbdg7ZDYXBCVAANxu9NA9HY0DgWIo4lQAi4-wAFDA5ah2D5QNBOYFXph4mC7ltxHREABKfh8kR8wVUDAuT4Pd6-W6KeX81WpfSNZF4skgsFdXGowKMrFdOIJYNJLpA8l%200AtMqnCNdLQYdgekktfSocT0bqnLq9KgMmOSsbjY36O1vK43f7yAB8ALUOwwknQKhqamjrp8qQAdDlpiZVgAlBiQQXc-YAA1g5GnBM4DFKGFoqUwkEwpxVVFioD5iFgytVXihMP08pdbvgffj5VA8kfGjcxtAAH4NABZCqgYLf5jqMaQ5IlY3r6D2-ZeoG9jAaAAZomSEE3vBgSwasADqHDirsPKgEhfYpuwfakncJIlkk%205MFazD0l4pL6AQhJJFevY3oRxEtEBXjUrSyrgdeBHaH2haoMYizMnwKxgOy2y7OwZQkswNFJKgOH7D4sAiN0-i7P8uEtm2clUBwe7kFQrh7Lgorinq5DSrKwryvAFxYKA8AwvYxwoMwJLihpuxoJZoDTpapw2pAVbfI6TALnZMrKqagjCKuGkiIoYiSNIshMIJqZ9tZ8qhdatr3NWPy1qgxoQlJoAEFgkAAO5BTszDiD4q6QOQQVFTRvBJSwkAwn21LMYQpB9r6WJzrE8qpRgXTZj4PhdK0xpVUAA) containing this solution.